# Angular 9: Scoping Issues Using Named Functions as Arguments for then(), listen(), and subscribe()

Tags: angular, scoping

Having some trouble understanding why I'm having scoping issues.

When using functions defined inside of `then()`, everything works fine:

```js
import GoogleAuth = gapi.auth2.GoogleAuth;
import GoogleUser = gapi.auth2.GoogleUser;

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  constructor() { }

  private googleAuth: GoogleAuth = undefined;
  private clientConfig = { ... };

  public init(): void {
    gapi.load('auth2', () => {
      gapi.auth2.init(this.clientConfig)
        .then((response: GoogleAuth) => {
          this.googleAuth = response;
      });
    });
  }
}
```

But, when I try to use a named function as argument for then(), I get an error (next to line in code):

```js
import GoogleAuth = gapi.auth2.GoogleAuth;
import GoogleUser = gapi.auth2.GoogleUser;

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  constructor() { }

  private googleAuth: GoogleAuth = undefined;
  private clientConfig = { ... };

  private onInit(response: GoogleAuth): void {
    console.log(this); // undefined
    this.googleAuth = response; // Cannot read property 'googleAuth' of undefined
  }

  public init(): void {
    gapi.load('auth2', () => {
      gapi.auth2.init(this.clientConfig)
        .then(this.onInit);
    });
  }
}
```

I thought at first it was because I assigned *undefined* as the value for "googleAuth", but even if I run "console.log(this);" inside of "onInit", *undefined* is what appears in the console. If I were to call the method manually and pass the expected parameters, it has no trouble seeing "this" and "this.googleAuth". I have the exact same issues when using listen() and subscribe().

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you passed in the function `this.onInit` to `then`, you looses the context. Proper way to do it is

```js
    public init(): void {
      gapi.load('auth2', () => {
        gapi.auth2.init(this.clientConfig)
          .then((resp) => this.onInit(resp));
        });
    }
```

Note the use of fat arrow function.

Comment: Thank you! That has been driving me up a wall!